# How to create multiple C++ custom actions in single custom action project?

Tags: c++, wix

Is there anyway to make multiple C++ custom actions in single C++ custom action project.
I'm using WiX Toolset v3.10 and Visual Studio 2015.
I guess it may be done with C# but i don't want to use C# and .Net for my custom actions.
I just want to create single .dll for all of my custom actions.
Is this even possible? If possible can you give me an example?
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You just add all your exported custom action entrypoints to the single Dll, that's all it takes. It's not clear from the question why you can't do this.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I did not know that you can add all of your custom actions to the CustomAction.def and the CustomAction.cpp file. I tried to add my 2 custom actions to the CustomAction.cpp file but it didn't work. Then I added my other custom action to the CustomAction.def file (thanks to you) now it works. Actually community is cruel because they voted down my question while they can help. If community is trying to help people (like they said) then they can't just vote down the question and leave. It does **NOT** make any sense.

Comment: The community is not monolithic - different people act differently. That said, your question reads like a general plea for a help (especially the request for example) rather than a clear explanation of what you've tried and what about it doesn't work. Thus the text "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" seems applicable and some vote down. (As an aside, if you don't know how to create multiple entry points in DLLs, writing custom actions is not likely a good fit for your skillset.)

Comment: Odds are a custom action isn't even needed.  It's a strange dilemma.... writing CAs should not be undertaken lightly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look through this WiX source code for examples on writing C++ custom actions.

https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/tree/develop/src

Look at: wix3 / src / ext / ca / wixca / dll /

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There are really good examples in that directory. Sadly i can't upvote your answer because i don't have enough reputation :)

Comment: You could accept my answer.  That will earn you reputation.